# Where to add <head> element in angularjs html templates?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to include a template html with angularjs like:

```
<div ng-include src="'template/slider.html'"></div>
```

I will take the template from http://www.jssor.com, which requires also some `<head><script>...` tags in the template itself:

**Question**: is it the correct way to create a template with a schema as follows, or should I move the  elements somewhere else?

slider.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
            ...
        };
    </script>
</head>

    <div id="slider1_container">
        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div ... />
        <script>jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');</script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please be aware that dynamically added `<script>` tags, in the `<head>` or not, may behave differently to hard coded ones in terms of _async_.

Comment: I'd be happy to take any advise on how this could be correctly implemented.

Comment: You probably need not add `<head>` tag

Comment: Multiple <head>s are not a good practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575384/html-multiple-heads

Answer (score 1):

Your angular templates do not need to have the `<head>` tag, there should only be one `<head>` tag in your html page, and it should not be enclosed between the `<body>` tags. Having multiple `<head>` tags breaks validation and will cause unpredictable behavior.