# How to preload an image in Angular when visiting a specific route

Tags: angular

To improve the performance of an Angular 12 SSR web app, I would like to preload an image on the home page. Currently, we have a `link` element in our `index.html`, but that preloads the image on every route, not just the home page.

```html
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://example.com/assets/img/bg/hero_image.png" />
```

Additionally, I am lazy-loading the path/module:

```js
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomePageModule),
},
```

It seems like you [cannot add a <head> element in the home page template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921431/where-to-add-head-element-in-angularjs-html-templates).

What options do I have to preload the image as early as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a service to inject a preload `link` element in the head of the document. And then calling the service in components where I wanted to add the preloaded assets, inside `ngOnInit()`.

To be able to do this though, I had to pass the component's renderer and head to the service as well as the asset for which I created an interface.

The Service:

```
//services/preloader-service/preload.service.ts

import { Injectable, Inject, Renderer2, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { PreloadableAsset } from './preloadable-asset.type';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PreloadService {
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: object) {}

    makePreloadable(link: string, as: string, media?: string) {
        if (as === 'image') {
            const type = 'image/' + link.split('.').pop();
            const asset: PreloadableAsset = {
                as,
                href: link,
                type,
                media,
            };
            return asset;
        }
    }

    preloadAsset(renderer: Renderer2, head: HTMLHeadElement, asset: PreloadableAsset) {
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId) && asset.href) {
            const preloader = renderer.createElement('link');
            renderer.setAttribute(preloader, 'rel', 'preload');
            renderer.setAttribute(preloader, 'href', asset.href);
            if (asset.as === 'image') {
                renderer.setAttribute(preloader, 'as', asset.as);
                if (asset.type) {
                    renderer.setAttribute(preloader, 'type', asset.type);
                }
                if (asset.media) {
                    renderer.setAttribute(preloader, 'media', asset.media);
                }
            }
            renderer.appendChild(head, preloader);
        }
    }
}
```

The Interface:

```
export interface PreloadableAsset {
    as?: string;
    type?: string;
    href: string;
    media?: string;
}
```